# Is there a possibility to use LaTeX on Facebook?

Tags: macros, metadata

Is it possible to use LaTeX in facebook?
I have tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-Y6UbA6y-U) tutorial, but I did not find the extension in my chrome.

Comment: I really like the fish in that video.  Apart from that it is off-topic, I guess.  Also, why is your question tagged [tag:biblatex] and [tag:bibtex]?

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you edit to put more relevant tags please?

Comment: Well, the question is not on TeX/LaTeX, but rather on some Google Chrome Addons.  It is thus not relevant for this site in general, regardless of the tags.  I was just thinking, that perhaps you wanted to exploit the capabilities of [tag:bibtex] to post nicely formatted citations on Facebook.  If you were looking for that, you might be interested in [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Comment: It seems off-topic to me, too, but please don't delete it. The question will probably be closed, but remain still available in case someone has the same question again in the future. And it has been answered already!

Comment: Ok I will not delete, but please don't downvote

Comment: It seems that Facebook now has some [support for LaTeX in chat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering/2397727#2397727). (Although I would be interesting to find more details about this somewhere.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can but it is only possible on Google Chrome. There is an extension , that you may find [here](http://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/poipbfekjfkiblpnimhjjmdecjjiblhm/) . Then MathJaX script will be enabled and you will be able to write some -easy - mathematical equations.

Note that you should leave blank between the delimeters. That is something like this:

```
$ \frac{1}{4} $
```

otherwise it will not compile. For example the code `$\frac{1}{4}$` does not qualify in facebook.That's all I think.

And yes, I think that this is off topic.

Comment: Have you tried to download this? I'm not sure that it is possible from the link that you gave.

Comment: You are right. Something's wrong with this extension. I could swear it worked 5 months ago. Hmm.. that's weird.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-all-the-things/cbimabofgmfdkicghcadidpemeenbffn

Comment: @Oscar thanks for the link. I am using Firefox anymore so I don't bother with Chrome extensions. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: As of today this feature seems to be no longer supported. At least not with my freshly installed desktop messenger for Windows.